# GMock doesn't compile - GTEST_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_REQUIRED seems to not be defined

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to build a simple mocked class

```cpp
#include "interpolation.hpp"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class MockInterp1D : public Interp1DBase {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(evaluateAt, double(double));
    MOCK_METHOD2(evaluateAt, double(double, int));
};
```

based on the following base class

```cpp
class Interp1DBase {
public:
    virtual double evaluateAt(double) const = 0;
    virtual double evaluateAt(double, int) const = 0;
    virtual ~Interp1DBase() { };
};
```

using Google Mocks. When I try to compile the tests where this mock is used, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:61,
                 from /home/tlycken/exjobb/Code/alpha-orbit-follower/test/interpolation/interpolation-mocks.hpp:4,
                 from /home/tlycken/exjobb/Code/alpha-orbit-follower/test/physics/B-field-tests.hpp:6,
                 from /home/tlycken/exjobb/Code/alpha-orbit-follower/test/physics/B-field-tests.cpp:2:
/usr/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:134:41: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   bool VerifyAndClearExpectationsLocked()
                                         ^
```

and then literally hundreds of similar syntax or definition errors all pointing to files within GMock.

I took a look at `gmock-spec-builder.h:134`, and found the following (in some context):

```
// Verifies that all expectations on this mock function have been
// satisfied.  Reports one or more Google Test non-fatal failures
// and returns false if not.
bool VerifyAndClearExpectationsLocked()
    GTEST_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_REQUIRED_(g_gmock_mutex);
```

which led me to believe that `GTEST_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_REQUIRED_` might be a macro that for some reason wasn't defined. And indeed, after digging through all header files included from either `gmock/gmock.h` or `gtest/gtest.h` I still haven't found the definition of that macro.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**UPDATE:**

I've been able to produce an even simple minimal example:

```
// in file mock-test.cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
// Yeah, that's the only content
```

Compile with

```
g++ -o mock-test.o -c mock-test.cpp
```

Causes the same error.

I've installed GMock through `sudo apt-get install google-mock`, which gave me a folder under `/usr/src` where I could run `cmake .` followed by `make` to generate library files which I copied to `/usr/lib`. The header files were already in `/usr/include` so I didn't do anything about them manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same error when I tried to compile using gmock 1.7 with gtest 1.6. Make sure you are using the same version of gtest.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem - I had used `gtest` before, and then I installed it using `sudo apt-get install gtest`, which apparently brought in version 1.6. When I added `gmock` to the project, it wasn't available in the package repo, so I grabbed the source, version 1.7 - which bundled `gtest` 1.7. However, since I still had the older `gtest` headers and libraries in my search path (somewhere under `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`) `gcc` seemed to prefer grabbing them from there instead, causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use g-mock in `gcc`.
But basically we use in windows like this.
Your class definitions are right.
Did you use those functions like

`EXPECT_CALL(classobj, exact functionname as it looks in definition).AtLeast(Times(0)).Return(0);`

then

`classobj.exact functionname as it looks in definition()`

Try this I think it should work. If you want it in detail, just let me know I will expand the same with some typical example.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! However, this fails before I get as far as trying to mock anything - see the update for a simpler example that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: Write the body, why did you write only `#include <gmock/gmock.h>`?

Comment: @TomasLycken: Did you configure `gmock properly`? I mean `libs` and all that. You need to providr gmock and gtest `libs` to your project

Comment: I didn't write anything more just to produce something as short as possible that reproduces the error. If I write a class body or not is irrelevant - the compiler doesn't even get there, since it chokes on gmock.h. I've tried compiling with all flags to include gmocks and gtest libraries, but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are the appropriate sources & headers in the /usr/src/gmock folder.

Your job is only overwrite the whole content of folders:

```
/usr/src/gmock/gtest/src -> /usr/src/gtest/src
/usr/src/gmock/gtest/cmake -> /usr/src/gtest/cmake
/usr/src/gmock/gtest/CMakeLists.txt-> /usr/src/gtest/CMakeLists.txt

/usr/src/gmock/gtest/include/gtest -> /usr/include/gtest/
```